# How to create an 'attack' function for a plants vs zombie text game

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a plants vs zombie type of game through printing but am stuck now on how to go about getting each units in each row to attack and how to implement a current HP sort of thing for each zombie as well, I'm trying to creating a nested loop to go through each row and column in my map (which is a nested array), and if detected a peashooter and zombie, print damaged taken and all and the zombie will then take damage based on a random number, but now it just loops printing lane A like 30+ times

```py
import random

peashooter = {'shortform' : 'PEASH',
          'name': 'Peashooter',
          'maxHP': 5,
          'min_damage': 1,
          'max_damage': 4,
          'price': 5
          }

zombie = {'shortform': 'ZOMBI',
          'name': 'Zombie',
          'maxHP': 15,
          'min_damage': 3,
          'max_damage': 6,
          'moves' : 1,
          'reward': 2
          }

field = [ [("PEASH"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None, None],
          [None, ("PEASH"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15")],
          [None, None, ("PEASH"," 5/5 "), None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None],
          [None, ("PEASH"," 5/5 "), None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None, None],
          [("PEASH"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15")] ]

num_rows=len(field)
num_columns=len(field[0])
row_indexes="ABCDE" # this is for me to name each array/row

def defender_attack(defender_name, field, row, column):
    damage= random.randint(1,4)
    
    print('{} in lane {} shoots {} for {} damage'.format(defender_name['shortform'], row_indexes[x], zombie['shortform'], damage))
    #zombie  'currenthp' -= damage #trying to figure out how to implement a hp system that can store all zombies hp 
    #if zombie[' hp '] <= 0:
         #print('someone died')
        #element = None
    return

#start of code
x=0
for row in field:
    isPeash, isZombi = False, False
    for cell in row:
        if cell: 
            name, hp = cell
            if name == 'PEASH': isPeash = True
            elif name == 'ZOMBI': isZombi = True
        if isPeash and isZombi == True:
            for column in row:
                defender_attack(peashooter,field,row,column)
```

This is what I'm hoping to achieve but for it to work in all lanes too

```
Archer in lane D shoots Zombie for 4 damage!
Zombie in lane D advances!
    1     2     3
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
A|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
B|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
C|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
D|PEASH|     |     |     |     |ZOMBI|     |
 | 5/5 |     |     |     |     |11/15|     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
E|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: This is cool idea. But isn't really a SO sort of question because it's missing some focus. Here's how to fix it: What specific problem are you trying to solve and where it the problem in your code? Then remove everything that doesn't address that part.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I guess i need help in how to implement or create my function, there isn't any problem in my code right now but it's not working the way i want it to, so i need some help in pointing me in the right direction

Comment: The tile is so awesome that you should earn 100 reputation points only for that! ;) Btw: Did you already know https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Maybe this will help to focus the question. I am dying to read it. Btw: Your picture you are linking to is simple ASCII monotype text. Can you copy and paste that text and format it as code please?

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding the part of my code which didn't work as intended previously and how the output should look like